# Outlook 2007 Vertical Align two images in a td without support for css vertical-align: middle

Tags: image, html-email, vertical-alignment, html-table

Building an html email; I have two img tags in 1 td, one image (right side one) has a fixed height and the left one has a variable height. I want to be able to keep the images vertically aligned in the td middle. I can get it to work great in all browsers but Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013 due to its lack of the css property for vertical-align:middle.

Here is the markup:

```
 <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#673695" style="color:#ffffff;padding:14px 0 14px 14px;text-align:left;line-height:44px;vertical-align:middle;">
         <img src="lowreslogo.png" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;">      
         <img src="email_logo_newspaper.png" border="0" width="150" style="vertical-align: middle;">
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this keep in mind the restrictions that are found in email design?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<td valign="middle">`

using align and valign are best practice in email.

edit:
Try wrapping your images in a table or div, and use the valign on the parent table cell.

Comment: Yah i had tried this prior as well and had no results... just Outlook being outlook... Outlook is the IE of the email world cant win with it but everyone uses it...

Comment: @estern added more to my answer.